# How to make box with padding that works in Outlook?

Tags: css, outlook, html-email, tablelayout

I found myself designing email HTML and CSS and I am trying to make a button with colored background and some padding around text (which is vertically and horizontally centered) that works in Outlook 2007/2010/2013

```html
<span style="background: orange;
      padding: 5px 10px;">Foo bar</span>
```

How do I make it happen in Outlook?

I suspect that answers involves a table with some deprecated HTML attributes from 1990s.

Answer (score 10):

A nice way I saw is to add borders like this (makes a padding feeling):

```
<a id="button-a-tag" style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; background-color: #256F9C; border-top: 15px solid #256F9C; border-bottom: 15px solid #256F9C; border-left: 25px solid #256F9C; border-right: 25px solid #256F9C; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; display: inline-block;">my button</a>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adVeQO - codepen how it looks on browser

this is how it looks on outlook -

[image: this is how it looks on outlook]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following button. This will look great across all clients.

```
<!-- START GREEN BUTTON -->
<center>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" width="100%" style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px;">
                        &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#87be45" width="150" style="-moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;">
                                        <a href="http://www.example.com" style="padding: 10px;width:150;display: block;text-decoration: none;border:0;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px;font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, 'Open Sans';color: #ffffff;background: #87be45;border: 1px solid #87be45;-moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;line-height:17px;" class="button_link">
                                            Get Started!
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" width="100%" style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px;">
                        &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
<!-- END GREEN BUTTON -->
```

Comment: I believe it should be centered in all clients: https://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/display/summary/tJkftnOkpk9BCG8R3WbFGV1DXMCHgJ454NIbx0KkOGeQX/shared

Answer (score 1):

The best place to make buttons that work across all email clients is using: http://buttons.cm/ - aka Bulletproof Buttons.  This uses MSO conditional and VML to make the button for Outlook and then uses HTML and CSS to create for all other clients. You may want to wrap this in a nested table to help control positioning and padding/margin, etc around it.

Using your example, see below for sample code created from this tool:

```
<div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="#" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:100px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="orange">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="#"
style="background-color:orange;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:100px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Foo Bar</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
```

****EDIT****

In response to issue with Office 365, I am posting the code that I usually use for buttons across browsers. It is a bit bulky and includes a couple reiterations of code and styling, but it prevents the double button when forwarded/replied to in outlook and displays accurately across all clients.  See below for code and here for EOA test link(https://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/display/summary/8XvVSO9BwdO6wlPYYbmAh9aUAiaHrEaPW3OArDYU9Lc7H/shared)

```
<table align="center" width="280" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                      <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="padding:20px; border-collapse:collapse; display:block; text-align:center;">
                      <div><!--[if mso]>
      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://sample.com" style="height:50px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:250px;" arcsize="9%" strokecolor="#B3668d" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" color="#93466d" />
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="text-align:center; color:#FFFFFF; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:28px; text-align:center; letter-spacing:1.5px;"><b>THIS BUTTON</b></center>
  </v:roundrect>
  <style>
  .button {
    color:#FFFFFF !important;
    width: 1px !important;
    background-color:#FFFFFF !important;
    border:0 !important;
    border-radius:0px !important;
    display:none !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1px !important;
    line-height:1px !important;
    height:1px
    overflow:hidden !important;
    mso-hide:all;
    }
  </style>
  <div style="width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden; display:none !IMPORTANT; visibility:hidden; line-height: 1px; border: 0; font-size:1px; mso-line-height: exactly; mso-hide:all; color:#FFFFFF;">
<![endif]--><a class="button" href="https://sample.com"
style="background-color:#93466d; border:2px solid #B3668d; border-radius:10px; color:#FFFFFF; display:inline-block; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:28px; line-height:50px ;text-align:center; text-decoration:none; width:250px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; mso-hide:all;"><b>THIS BUTTON</b></a><!--[if mso]></div><![endif]--></div>
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Actually this "bulletproof" button doesn't work in Outlook 365.
https://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/display/summary/8sMSd81qBpW4zWdre4DRwt5MZww3lHwmVyKiMGxqiJaTc/shared

Comment: Perhaps a combination of the two then? Combining the table with the a tag and VML should make it displayed and clickable on Outlook and All others. I never ran into this issue before - I think it is likely because was using color name and not hex or rgb value. Will take a look once I get a minute.

Comment: sorry for the delay in response, but my edited answer should now fix the issue you found above.

Comment: Yeah, I recently realized that their button only looks like it doesn't work in Outlook 365 because you need a real URL in there. I was being too hard on them!

Comment: :) Keep up the great work you guys do at EOA! I am a big fan.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2010 ignore any padding if you use anywhere margin. Use only margin or only padding.